# Precompile Android layouts to speed up views creation

Tags: android, performance

It is possible to precompile Android layout XML files to speed up views/activities creation?

For example to write something like `new MyLayoutInstance(context);` instead of `layoutInflator.Inflate(Resource.layout.my_layout);`

Does this technique will make a sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

XML layout is inflated at runtime.

However, you can use Anko library to create layout programmatically.
[This article](https://android.jlelse.eu/400-faster-layouts-with-anko-da17f32c45dd) and [this post on medium](https://medium.com/@c2q9450/performance-comparison-building-android-ui-with-code-anko-vs-xml-layout-cc0abb21c561) suggest that Anko layouts are much faster than XML layout.

In general, creating layouts programmatically is much more efficient than XML based layout. But the code will be cumbersome to write. On the other hand, XML based layout allows us to preview the changes without actually running the code.

Now, the Anko library reduces the code complexity by removing a lot of boilerplate code.
Also, there is a plugin that allows us to see the Anko layout without running the code, though it is not as good as XML layout preview.